# How to Provide security to sms in android by using RSA algorithm

Tags: android, rsa, encryption

I want to send encrypted Sms data by using one key(public) for encryption and this sms wnat to decrypt by using different private key...specifically i want to use RSA algorithm scenario...

So can u tell me how to encrypt and decrypt data by using different keys in android...

I use DES algorithm but its using same key ....

can anybody suggest how to do this.... me blank value.....

`

```
public String encrypt(String smsbody) {
    try {

        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");

        kpg.initialize(512);// initialize key pairs to 512 bits ,you can
                            // also take 1024 or 2048 bits

        KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();

        PublicKey publi = kp.getPublic();
        System.out.println(publi.serialVersionUID);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publi);

        byte[] src = smsbody.getBytes();// converting source data into byte
                                        // array

        byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(src);// use this method to
                                                // finally encrypt data

        String srco = new String(cipherData);// converting byte array into
                                                // string
        // System.out.println();
        // System.out.println("Encrypted data is:-" + srco);

        return srco;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return "";
}

public PrivateKey Privatekey() {

    try {
        kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");

        kpg.initialize(512);// initialize key pairs to 512 bits ,you can
                            // also take 1024 or 2048 bits

        KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
        privatei = kp.getPrivate();// Generating private key
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return privatei;
}

public String decrypt(String smsbody, PrivateKey privatei) {
    try {

        Cipher cipheri = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");

        cipheri.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privatei);// Setting to
                                                    // decrypt_mode


        System.out.println(smsbody);

        byte[] cipherDat = cipheri.doFinal(smsbody.getBytes());// Finally
                                                                // decrypting
        // data
        System.out.println(cipherDat);
        String decryptdata = new String(cipherDat);


        return decryptdata;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return "";
} `
```

I am trying this following code but when i use decrypt it will give

Thanks in advance...

Comment: SMS messages are implemented differently through com carriers. Depending on your scenario, you might encounter problems with : length of the SMS(s), characters allowed, encoding, etc.

Comment: Thanks Iraklis...I am new in android development...Can u provide me any link to my question..

Comment: There is too much wrong with your code to answer this, especially since you are not just "blank value" but your error message is too. One hint: the public key and private key should be of the same key pair to make RSA work.